# crosscheck x with z?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, grammaticality, sentence-structure

I am not sure about my use of the word `crosscheck`.

I have a sentence similar to:

> To ensure the program correctness, we manually crosscheck the
>   program's xyz function, and the product expiration and validation
>   results, with results provided by the zzz program and the yyy tool, on
>   a random sample of a few hundred products.

To clarify: I have a program which performs some functions. I compared the results of this program's functions against those provided by another program and tool. I want to say this is the way I used to test its correctness.

Is my sentence readable, correct, and conveys the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a normal use of the term ***[crosscheck](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crosscheck)***. It is generally used in the form *crosscheck A with B*, or *crosscheck A against B*. In the case of *with*, it can mean comparing two methods of doing a calculation or processing data, or it can mean asking another person. For example:

> We crosschecked the results of the calculator's trigonometric functions with three known-good models of calculator.
>   Bob has told me what happened at the meeting, but I want to crosscheck with Alice.

In the case of *against*, it can be comparing two methods, or checking a list or dataset to make sure the results are the same.

> We crosschecked the results of the calculator's trigonometric functions against standard trig tables.

It can also be used without a specific source if you are just talking about the need to crosscheck, or if you are speaking to the person you are crosschecking with.

> So, the software is now running without errors, but we still need to crosscheck its results.
>   Bob told me what happened at the meeting, but I just wanted to call you in order to crosscheck.